# Why does Sass transpile @use into target CSS file?

Tags: css, sass

I'm learning Sass and am having a problem.  When my .scss file gets transpiled into a .css file, the @use directive gets copied from the .scss file into the .css file and the styles are not rendered.

/scss/main.scss:

```
@use 'reset';
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

/scss/reset.scss

```
html,
body,
ul,
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

/css/main.css is compiling into this:

```
@use 'reset';
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

However, main.css should look like this:

```
html, body, ul, ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
}
```

It's my understanding that the @use directive in main.css is an error and VS Code, which is my editor, highlights it as such.  I'm using the Live Sass Compiler extension for VS Code.

Comment: That's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@import` to replace `@use`, and it's without space in _reset.sass file

I try success in online [SASS Compile](https://sass.js.org/).

```
// /scss/main.sass
@import 'reset';
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

// /scss/_reset.sass
html,
body,
ul,
ol{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

[image]

Comment: Renaming the reset file and using import instead of use did prevent the @import directive from appearing in main.css but if I change _reset.scss, e.g. by increasing the margin, the change doesn't appear in main.css.

Comment: @Ray I fixed the issue.